# bs4 - extract specific href depending other value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So, I am trying to extract a specific href form example those below, by giving the size ID.... for example I want the one with value EU='39' I want to be able to print exactly the href that is written in the line where EU 39 is allocated

```
  <a href="/p/nike-air-force-1-07-prm-x-carhartt-wip-av4113-200-83890-83891" EU='38,5' US='6'>38,5</a>
                  <li title="">
                    <a href="/p/nike-air-force-1-07-prm-x-carhartt-wip-av4113-200-83890-83892" EU='39' US='6,5'>39</a>
                  <li title="">
                    <a href="/p/nike-air-force-1-07-prm-x-carhartt-wip-av4113-200-83890-83893" EU='40' US='7'>40</a>
                  <li title="">
                    <a href="/p/nike-air-force-1-07-prm-x-carhartt-wip-av4113-200-83890-83894" EU='40,5' US='7,5'>40,5</a>
                  <li title="">
                    <a href="/p/nike-air-force-1-07-prm-x-carhartt-wip-av4113-200-83890-83895" EU='41' US='8'>41</a>
                  <li title="">
```

My code until now is this below. I found out how to get the single hrefs, but I just want those with my wished size ID and also with specific keywords. I tried and it worked, but it just found all with that keyword.... and I would like to get just those with a specific value...

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"}
s = requests.session()
scraper=cfscrape.create_scraper(sess=s)

link=input("link where I need to find the product: ")
keyword=["examplekeyword"]
def bs_id():

    try:
        r = scraper.get(link, timeout=2, verify=False, headers=header)

    except:
        print("error while connecting...")
        try:
            r = scraper.get(link, timeout=2, verify=False, headers=header)
        except:
            print("error while connecting")

            return

    page = bs(r.text, "html.parser")

    raw_links = page.findAll("a")
    hrefs = []

    for raw_link in raw_links:
        try:
            hrefs.append(raw_link["href"])
        except:
            pass

    for href in hrefs:
        found = False
        for keyword in keywords:
            if(keyword.upper() in href.upper()):
                found = True
                if("http" in href):
                    product_page = href
                else:
                    product_page = site + href
```

Hopefully anyone of you can help me, I am really new to this so every helping comment would be kind. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try `page.select('a[eu=39]')`. This should select all `a` tags that have an `eu` attribute, with value `39`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this, rather than looping through hrefs, just loop through the whole "a" tag, and then get the href you want.  That way you only need one loop.

```
for link in page.find_all('a'):
    if "EU='39'" in link:
        print(link['href'])
```

Comment: Awesome!  Glad I could help.  :)  If it wouldn't be too much trouble, clicking this answer as "accepted" gives me points that do...something...not sure what yet lol, but it does keep us in the skinner box so, in general, check the box if you end up using the code.  ;)